# Ubuntu 18.10 - unable to install NPM

Tags: apt, npm

I tried to install npm and I repeatedly got error that NPM depends on package node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but that package is not installable.

I have no packages broken (I search for them using dpkg) but I still can not install NPM.

I can install just nodejs but I need also npm...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also deletes apt cache, update all sources, purge already installed nodejs and still nothing.

Comment: those packages may not be in the cuttle repo yet, not sure?

Comment: See here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/node-npm-bundled_1.0.3-1_all.deb.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get it installed with these steps if the above comments methods doesn;t fly:

```
# For the soon to be LTS release, 10.x
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

# For the bleeding edge, 11.x
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then install with `sudo apt install nodejs`.

Comment: Your welcome grateful to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall node and install it again with Node Version Manager(first install NVM,then with NVM node version you wish),on this way you will not have any problems with node-gyp or NPM .Good luck.

Comment: With NVM? When I tried apt-cache search nvm I got nothing....

Comment: Must install NVM first.

Comment: No, I do not want another utility - I have these troubles on Ubuntu before and I forgot how to solve it - but it was definitively pure apt way - no other utilities. But thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem,just trying to help.